# how to close xmldocument in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xamarin

I created an application for Android in Xamarin.I open an xml file ,then I save the changes. I need to close it but xmldocument has not any option to do that. 
How can I close the file? I really need to do this because on other activity I want to modify it and it says :"Sharing violation on path"

Comment: how you opened the file?please put your code there

Comment: yes,I opened the file with: myfile.load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the [XmlDocument.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wd18z.aspx) just put a using around the TextWriter should do it:

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();

        var filePath = "myXmlFile.xml";

        doc.Load(filePath);

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
```